# Setting nullable int to zero if value is less than zero

Tags: c#

Using c# I was wondering if there is a way to cast an int to return 0 if null or less than 0

```
  number = ((int?) nullableNum) ?? 0
```

This will return 0 if null but I want a way to return 0 if less than 0

Comment: `nullableNum ?? 0 < 0 ? 0 : nullableNum;`?

Comment: @HereticMonkey it shows _Operator '??' cannot be applied to operands of type 'int?' and 'bool'_

Comment: Ok, well, this seems rather trivial. Can you explain what trouble you’ve had?

Comment: You could also use a uint which is unsigned and cannot be less than zero.

Comment: `number = nullableNum switch { int i when i > 0 => i, _ => 0 };` Because `switch` expressions are what all the cool kids use these days. (I'm kidding; this is arguably not as clear since we're expressing the opposite condition.)

Comment: @JeroenMostert  According to Resharper you can change it to `nullableNum switch { { } i when i > 0 => i, _ => 0 }`.  How fun.

Comment: @juharr: well it's not wrong, but of course only a true sadist would follow that suggestion.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You can use `Math.Max` for that purpose, which will make the code more readable:

```
var number = Math.Max(0, nullableNum ?? 0)
```

or even better to use `GetValueOrDefault` instead of null-coalescing. It 
retrieves the value of the current `Nullable<T>`
 object, or the default value of the underlying type which is 0 for `Nullable‹int›`

```
var number = Math.Max(0, nullableNum.GetValueOrDefault());
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use the following syntax for that

```cs
var number = nullableNum.HasValue && nullableNum.Value > 0 ? nullableNum.Value : 0;
```

You check that `nullableNum` [`HasValue`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.nullable-1.hasvalue?view=netframework-4.8) and whether it's [`Value`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.nullable-1.value?view=netframework-4.8) greater `0` or not and return a `Value`. If condition is false (`nullableNum` is `null` and its value less `0`), simply return `0`

Another and more simple option is to use [`GetValueOrDefault`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.nullable-1.getvalueordefault?view=netframework-4.8) method for that, it return the default value for underlying type (`0` for `int`)

```cs
var defaultValue = nullableNum.GetValueOrDefault();
var number = defaultValue < 0 ? 0 : defaultValue;
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want an one-liner you could do (where nullable is your value or null):

```
int? nullable = null;
int zero = (nullable < 0 ? 0 : nullable) ?? 0;
```